# How do I write a JPA Modifying Query to update a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column correctly?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get the below modifying query to work:

```
    @Repository
    public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String> {
        @Modifying
        @Query(value = "UPDATE account " +
                "SET updated_as_of_date = ?1 WHERE status = 'VALID'", nativeQuery = true)
        void updateAllDates(LocalDateTime someDate);
    }
```

I am able to get the date component of the `someDate` method argument to save to the MySQL database correctly, **but not the time component**. After my test code calls `updateAllDates` with some LocalDateTime value, I fetch the updated record and the time component is always 00:00:00.

I get this same behavior of no time data being saved whether the `updated_as_of_date` column type is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

Why would the time component not save?

And yes, I believe I could/should refactor the above to NOT use custom Modifying Queries, and instead use standard batch JPA findAll and saveAll calls. But I am trying to understand what's missing for this approach above. Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using? Does it's driver support `LocalDateTime`? Have you tried an `Instant` or a good old `Date`?

Comment: I am using H2 with MYSQL mode. and spring-data-jpa 2.2.0.

Comment: What do you mean by fetch? Fetching the entity? If yes show the entity code. You say when you fetch you get 00:00:00. Is the time part saved in the DB? Have you looked there with MySQL Workbench or sth?